# Can not get the value after selecting from drop down list using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue.I can not fetch value from drop down list using Angular.js. I am explaining my code below.

```
    <select class="form-control"  id="user_name" ng-model="user_name" ng-options="user.name for user in listOfUser track by user.value " >
    </select>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="sendEvoucherCode();"  id="addProfileData" value="SEND"/>

$http({
            method:'GET',
            url:"php/getUserId.php",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            //console.log('user id',response);
            angular.forEach(response.data,function(data){
                var obj={'name':data.userid,'value':data.userid};
                $scope.listOfUser.push(obj);
            })
        },function errorCallback(response) {
        })

$scope.sendEvoucherCode=function(){
        console.log('check',$scope.user_name);

    }
```

Here when i am selecting value from drop down lost and clicked on any button,inside that function i can not get any value bu using this console `console.log('check',$scope.user_name.value);` .Here i need to retrive the selected value.Please help me.

Comment: Change `ng-change="removeBorder('user_name');` to `ng-change="removeBorder(user_name);`

Comment: Can you put together a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: yes a [mcve] would be great!

Comment: i selected a value but the generated output html is coming like `<option value="" label="Select User" selected="selected">Select User</option>` this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to Shb's comment.
Your calling the method (on ng-change) `removeBorder` with the parameter `'user_name'` which is a String. But you want the variable named `user_name`. So change your method call to `removeBorder(user_name)`.

**EDIT:**

The code is working. See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qkB11gj11B2X666q1Vvk?p=preview).

Comment: No,I am fetching value inside click event even i remove `ng-change` still the same issue.

Comment: @ christoph: i have already posted the code.Here i can say that i am fetching from data from db and showing them in drop down.

Comment: i have edited my post.When user is clicking the send button it is showing this `check Object {name: "Select User", value: ""}` message in console.

Comment: @satya The code you've already posted is correct. See this working plunker example. So please post more code or find the solution by yourself. http://plnkr.co/edit/qkB11gj11B2X666q1Vvk?p=preview Maybe you can show us the response from your request.

Comment: actually i am displaying this drop down list in one pop up modal window.There its not working properly.In my side also its coming in general page.